# Question related to Graph isomorphism.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Determine whether the given pair of graphs is isomorphic with reasoning.

My try:1st pair is isomorphic but not second pair .

[image]

Comment: Where's the reasoning?

Comment: For 1st pair there are 7 vertices with degree 2 and for an edge between two vertices there also  exist an image edge.

Comment: That would also be true of a graph with four vertices in a square and three in a triangle, no? (It's not clear what you mean by,"for an edge between two vertices also an image edge.")

Comment: For 2nd pair they also have 7 vertices with each has degree 2 but there is an edge between $u_1 $ and $u_2$ but not between $v_1$ and $v_4$.

Comment: How many components does a(left) have? How many does a(right)?

Comment: 7 components each

Comment: :) I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory) not vertices...

Answer (score 2):

The graphs in the first pair are isomorphic because there is a one-one correspondence between the vertices that induces a one-one coreespondence on the edges: $u_1\leftrightarrow v_1$, $u_2\leftrightarrow v_3$, $u_3\leftrightarrow v_5$, $u_4\leftrightarrow v_7$, $u_5\leftrightarrow v_2$, $u_6\leftrightarrow v_4$, $u_7\leftrightarrow v_6$.

The graphs in the second pair are not isomorphic because the first graph has a vertex, $u_3$, of degree three adjacent to two vertices, $u_2$ and $u_5$, of degree two, while the second graph has no such vertex.